# Symfony 4 - FOSUserBundle - Guard authenticators

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I'm trying to implement FOSUserBundle with guard on Symfony 4.1.
This is my authenticator :

```
<?php


namespace App\Security;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
use TargetPathTrait;

private $em;
private $router;
private $passwordEncoder;
private $csrfTokenManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, RouterInterface $router, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
}

public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->request->get('_username');
    $password = $request->request->get('_password');
    $csrfToken = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');

    if (false === $this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid(new CsrfToken('authenticate', $csrfToken))) {
        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException('Invalid CSRF token.');
    }

    $request->getSession()->set(
        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
        $username
    );

    return [
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
    ];
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $username = $credentials['username'];

    return $this->em->getRepository('App:User')
        ->findOneBy(['email' => $username]);
}

public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    $password = $credentials['password'];

    if ($this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $targetPath = null;

    // if the user hit a secure page and start() was called, this was
    // the URL they were on, and probably where you want to redirect to
    $targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey);

    if (!$targetPath) {
        $targetPath = $this->router->generate('homepage');
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
}

protected function getLoginUrl()
{
    return $this->router->generate('fos_user_security_login');
}

/**
 * Does the authenticator support the given Request?
 *
 * If this returns false, the authenticator will be skipped.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function supports(Request $request)
{
    if($request->attributes->get('_route') !== 'fos_user_security_login'){
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

this is my security.yaml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
#            form_login:
#               csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            remember_me:
                secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'

    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And the fos_user.yaml :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: 'orm'
    user_class: App\Entity\User
    firewall_name: main
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    from_email:
        address: "admin@test.com"
        sender_name: "test"
    registration:
        form:
            type: App\Form\UserRegistrationFormType
```

Whenever I go to login I get the following error :

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using
>   form_login in your security firewall configuration.

I have the security-bundle installed and tried going through the steps provided in the official documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

And I followed the tutorial on KnpUniversity but that was for Symfony 3 and it seems things do not work the same way anymore.

There must be something really obvious I'm not seeing.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Version info :
- Symfony ^4.1
- FOSUserBundle ^2.1
- security-guard ^4.1

Comment: Just a stab in the dark but I think you need to specify the `form_login` -- see (http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) as an example

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'll check it out and let you know

Comment: Did you ever solve the error? I am having the exact same problem.  What did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you understand better what is symfony guard and fos user bundle.
 [Symfony Guard - You don't need FOSUserBundle](https://speakerdeck.com/kunicmarko20/symfony-guard-you-dont-need-fosuserbundle?slide=11)

Comment: Mostly fine, but outdated, and kinda sucks (vide HashPasswordListener).

Comment: Didn't say it's the best to follow or anything but most of the stuff there are still needed only the implementation is a bit different. :-) @emix do you have better resources I'm always interested in reading more about symfony. :D

Comment: Services are not required thanks to autowiring. Custom [Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) would be better instead of the authenticator. And check out how cool are [user checkers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html).

Comment: Correct with the autowire feature services aren't required anymore. the user checkers is the way to handle groups and everything :D and i agree custom guard is much better that's why i shared that slide :) in fos user you just rewrite everything on your needs :(

Comment: Yeah that's why I never use it ;)

Comment: you could also write a basic guard implementation and extend it by your needs on every project but you can choose what you want for starters and from where you think you will need to extend based on older projects.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: I had an issue similar. If I remember correctly, you have to remove the route for the login page that is defined in the fos user bundle routes. I know I am being ambiguous, but check the routes. It's looking for a fosuser login page, while you are authenticating with guard.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate has a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To help fill out [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58457464/3025856), I think your login route should be `fos_user_security_check` instead of `fos_user_security_login`.

The `supports()` function in Symfony 4 will check the route after you submitted the form, which will go to `login_check` by default with `FOSUserBundle`, and then it will run your custom authenticator instead.

This might also be the reason why Symfony2 can work, because they hadn't yet added `supports()` back then.